Exceeding the Stat Chart in Hackmaster 5e
Hackmaster has detailed charts of the bonuses and maluses associated with any given stat. However, the charts do not hold enough rows.
If you're lucky enough to roll two 18s, you could put those in Looks and Charisma, select Elf as your race, Spend some of your BP on boosting Looks and Charisma, and have a starting Charisma score of 29.
Are the expanded Stat charts published anywhere? Should one logically extrapolate the charts out in needed for such matters? Should we treat all stats as capped at 20, besides Charisma and Constitution, which would be capped at 22?
